# Spring MVC HandlerInterceptor ignored in Java config

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to convert a Spring project from XML to Java config and have run into the following issue with HandlerInterceptors:

XML Config (works):

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.mycompany.MyHandlerInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Java Config (interceptor is never called)

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    protected void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new MyHandlerInterceptor());
    }

    // ...
}
```

According to the documentation, these two configurations should be equivalent, however in the Java config example the neither the pre or post handle methods are ever called?

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Works fine here. Have you used your debugger or added traces in the code to make sure that your MvcConfig class is loaded and the addInterceptors method called?

Comment: @JBNizet Yes. I added debug logging before/after the call to registry.addInterceptor() and they both were hit.

Comment: Try to add @EnableWebMvc to MvcConfig class. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391988/in-spring-3-1-can-mvcinterceptors-be-used-in-conjunction-with-configuration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was my own fault. I had overridden `requestMappingHandlerMapping()` in my MVC Java config and did not set the interceptors property on the custom `HandlerMapping` class.

```
@Bean
@Override
public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
    CustomRequestHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new CustomRequestHandlerMapping();
    handlerMapping.setOrder(0);
    handlerMapping.setInterceptors(getInterceptors()); // <-- This was missing
    return handlerMapping;
}
```